# Transfer of iPhone Ownership

Tags: iphone

I have an AT&T family plan.  My niece has an HTC smartphone and hates it.  I have a 3G iPhone.  I want to give her my iPhone and get a newer one with my upgrade.  I don't know how to transfer ownership of my 3G iPhone to my niece.  Do iPhones have SIM cards and if they do, how do you get to it?  Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Don't forget to backup/sync your iPhone 3G with iTunes before giving it to your niece. Once done you can restore it to factory settings to get your apps and data off it and give her a "fresh" iPhone. When you get your new iPhone sync it with iTunes and move your settings and apps over and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the sim card, insert the sim remover tool (that came in the box, shown below) or any other thing object such as a straightened paper clip, hair clip, etc. into the small hole on the top of the device to extract the sim card tray.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

iPhones do have SIM cards.

If you got the phone through AT&T, you will need to contact them about transferring ownership. I believe they recently began allowing iPhones to be unlocked, so check that out before doing anything else.